# Oauth identity user is not the .net identity user

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Using .net core 1... When someone signs up/logs in using oauth2, the identity ID is provided by oauth, even if there's a local user.  Is there a way to join up the oauth user with the local identity user?

Following this example - https://rameshksh.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/linkedin-authentication-in-asp-net-core/ you can either login using "Identity" or you can login using Oauth - they aren't connected.  Am I missing something obvious or is this just how it works?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not supposed to work that way...local account vs other providers accounts.....usually when you use oauth the first time a user logs in, you save it as a local user, that should be the best approach...or if you want a mixed approach, when the user logs in via oauth, then check if their info is associated by any means with one of your local user, if yes, then display a popup asking if you want to associate the oauth info to the local account and sent an email with a tokenized url to the local user in order to approve that association...local user > oauth for security.

Comment: That's as I understood it too, it just doesn't seem to be how every example i've read so far seems to work (on .net core...)

Comment: Yeah, there is a certain lack of topics on these one...we normally just find the basic stuff....that's when you start reading about oauth patterns and start doing your own version with your own design decisions, like save it or not as a local user for example, or check if is a local user while keeping your app secure...this is worth reading https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749

Comment: And here is another one https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this through some trial and error...

```
        app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "LinkedIn",
            DisplayName = "LinkedIn",

            ClientId = Configuration["linkedin:clientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["linkedin:clientSecret"],

            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin"),

            AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
            TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)",

            Scope = { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress", "w_share" },
            Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnTicketReceived = context =>
                {
                    // Indicate that we handled the login
                    context.HandleResponse();

                    // Default redirect path is the base path
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ReturnUri))
                    {
                        context.ReturnUri = "/";
                    }

                    context.Response.Redirect(context.ReturnUri);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    // Retrieve user info
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                    request.Headers.Add("x-li-format", "json"); // Tell LinkedIn we want the result in JSON, otherwise it will return XML

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

// Do database stuff to find user using parameters provided through oauth
// Perform identity sign in using sign in manager
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(dbUser, false);
                }
            }
        });

        app.Map("/login", builder =>
        {
            builder.Run(async context =>
            {
                // Return a challenge to invoke the LinkedIn authentication scheme
                await context.Authentication.ChallengeAsync("LinkedIn", properties: new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" });
            });
        });
```

It is the code in "OnTicketReceived" that prevents the middleware from dropping it's own cookie for *just* LinkedIn authentication.